# Sharing local image or video files in WP 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

it is possibile in Windows phone 8.1 silverlight share a MP4 or JPG or MP3?
from the examples it seems that you can only share text or links. 
is there another way?
Thanks

Comment: ... yeah like OneDrive

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know we can share images in WP8.1 using `DataTransferManager`.

reference: [Share two different things in Windows Phone 8.1 C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463373/)

I'm not very sure about sharing video files as yet!But have a look at this:

[How to share files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871371.aspx)

Comment: ok. Example it works. It is possibile in ShareUI WHATSAPP? thank you